# CString use in Qt Application

Tags: qt4

I want to use this code from my Qt application :

```
#ifndef AS_I2C__HPP__
#define AS_I2C__HPP__

#include <cstring>

#include "as_i2c.h"

class AsI2c
{
public:
    AsI2c(int aBusNumber);
    virtual ~AsI2c();

    long setSlaveAddr(unsigned char aAddr);
    long getSlaveAddr() const;

    long read(unsigned char *aData, size_t aSize) const;
    long write(unsigned char *aData, size_t aSize);

    long readReg(unsigned char aReg, unsigned char *aData, size_t aSize) const;
    long writeReg(unsigned char aReg, unsigned char *aData, size_t aSize);

    long readMsg(unsigned char *aWData, unsigned char aWriteSize, unsigned char *aRData, size_t aReadSize);

    long readRegByte(unsigned char aReg) const;
    long writeRegByte(unsigned char aReg, unsigned char aVal);

protected:
    mutable struct as_i2c_device *mDev;
};

#endif // AS_I2C__HPP__
```

Im using qt-everywhere 4.7 to cross-compile it, how can I do it? (the code is a c++ wrapper from lowlevels c functions).

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace char with QChar, string with QString in your Qt application. You need to include #include  in order to use these classes.

They are equivalent classes to native C/C++ char and string classes and allow automatic typecasting as well. When you need to invoke low level code, you can just type cast QChar to char and QString to string.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but it doesn't work, it like my #include is not taking effect in my mainwindow.h so I can't use my wrapped class at all, here is the qt log output:

Comment: `mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow::on_readBtn_e2p_clicked()':
make: Leaving directory `/home/mks/stage/gui_modimx/demo-build-desktop'
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `AsI2c::AsI2c(signed char)'
mainwindow.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `AsI2c::setSlaveAddr(QChar)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [demo] Error 1
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project demo (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'`

Comment: @user732663: That's a different problem. You forgot to include the library you're using on the linker command line and/or in the .pro file (if you're using QtCreator).

Comment: @Mihai Limbășan : Yes Im using it and I still don't know how to add my libas_devices_cpp.so to the .pro file, here is what I tried :  `LIBS += -L"/home/mks/stage/armadeus/buildroot/output/target/usr/lib/" -las_devices_cpp.so`